# UV editor distorted when applying texture to custom mesh

Tags: uv-image-editor

I tried applying a texture to a custom mesh:

[image]

However, the texture looks like this in the UV editor:

[image]

And when I go into edit mode with the object selected, all the 'shapes' in the UV editor are distorted.

[image]

What can I do to 'undistort' my texture to make it uniform?

Comment: Hello, so maybe unwrap your mesh again? For example with the Smart UV Project option, or cut some seams and simply choose Unwrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrap again, use the *Smart UV Project* option, which will cut the mesh along the desired angle (keep the default settings, it should work fine), then in the *UV Editor* move, rotate and scale the UVs as you want.